# Mongoose associations print in ngFor

Tags: angular, mongoose, associations, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have this user.js model

```
const userSchema = new Schema({

    name: String,
    ...
    skills: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'skill'
    }]
})
```

and the skill.js model

```
const skillSchema = new Schema({
     name: String,
     user: {
         type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'user'
     },
})
```

When i am getting all the users in Angular, in html i do:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of arrUsers">
     ...
     <span *ngFor="let skill of user.skills">
           ******{{PRINT skill name}}******
     </span  

</div>
```

User in mlab is like this:

```
{
    "name": "a user name"
    "skills": [
        {
            "$oid": "5c17a4269ef5b511ece55446"
        }
    ],
}
```

and skills:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c17a4269ef5b511ece55446"
    },
    "name": "JAVA",
    "user": {
        "$oid": "5bf44809a15006343bc95718"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

in user controller i get the users like this:

```
findAll: (req, res) => {
    User.find()
        .then(users => {
            res.json(users);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                msg: err.message
            });
        });
},
```

and the skills array of a user in arrUsers console logs this:

> ...
>   skills: Array(3)
>
> 0: "5c18dd0084a030698e17cd40"
>
> 1: "5c18dd0384a030698e17cd42"
>
> 2: "5c18dd0584a030698e17cd43"
>   ...

Should i populate skills in findAll with some way?

What is the best way to print skill name?

**SOLUTION**

> I had to do User.find().populate('skills') in my controller

Thanks to Zlatko answer

Comment: Please post `arrUsers` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to populate the skills on querying it.

Something like:

```
db.users.get(query).populate('skills')
```

Then your skills array should be populated.

Comment: Thanks Zlatko! I had to populate in my controller

Answer (score 0):

simply print `skill.name`

```
<span *ngFor="let skill of user.skills">
       {{skill.name}}
 </span
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just simple binding, use your code like this -

```
 <span *ngFor="let skill of user.skills">
   {{skill?.name}}   //Here skill is your object contains data having keys name and user
 </span>
```

PS: In order to debug always better to use `json` pipe in template side like this -

```
{{skill | json}}
```

Comment: Hey pardeep! thanks for the answer! When i do the pipe it just prints the _id of the skill. skill.name is undefined. maybe i should post more code?

Comment: Yes, better is you post your response. There must be key having name `name` in your object

Comment: I think i did all the edits needed, thank you for your effort